# toolchain command can't be found

Tags: python, ios, kivy, toolchain

I am trying to create an ios app on my mac. I've run into a problem where I am trying to use toolchain, but my mac is unable to find it.
I first ran this:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config
brew link libtool
```

then sudo pip install Cython==0.29.17 (however initially I used a the wrong Cython version and it crashed)

then I created a folder and cloned a repo into it. `git clone git://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios`

I cd into the kivy-ios from it which has these files:

```
> CHANGELOG.md      kivy_ios        tests LICENSE           requirements.txt    toolchain.py
> README.md     setup.py        tox.ini
```

and then when I try running sudo ./toolchain.py build python3 openssl kivy
I keep getting

```
sudo ./toolchain.py: command not found
```

Is this an issue with sudo or me not configuring toolchain correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are not specifying to run this file with Python.

Instead do:

```
sudo python ./toolchain.py
```

Comment: I tried that and then got another unwelcome gift:   RAN: /usr/bin/xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator --show-sdk-path

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
xcrun: error: SDK "iphonesimulator" cannot be located
xcrun: error: SDK "iphonesimulator" cannot be located
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'Path' in SDK 'iphonesimulator'

Comment: @jkidd22 You can check the solution here: https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/259